# Scope operator needed to find std namespace instead of boost

Tags: c++, boost, scope, cuda, thrust

I am working on porting parts of the boost library to compile under cuda / nvcc as device functions. This involves using the thrust library for some things like iterators, arrays, etc. One issue I am finding is a compile error in the thrust library such as:

```
    C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\include\thrust/iterator/iterator_traits.h(66): error : namespace "boost::std" has no member "ptrdiff_t"
```

which is triggered by the line in thrust:

```
   typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
```

I can fix this by adding the scope operator :: ahead of the std lib call like:

```
   typedef ::std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
```

but clearly it is not okay to modify thrust.

Does anyone know why I am getting this issue? i.e. why does the thrust header iterator_traits.h search for std::ptrdiff_t inside the namespace boost::std rather than std? Is there a way to reverse this before I include the thrust header?

It is not easy to provide a minimal working example here due to the nature of porting a large library like boost.

Thanks!

Comment: Include the thrust headers before the boost ones?  Also, are you using using namespace directives?

Comment: I'm amending the thousands of boost include files to be device compatible. So the thrust includes are deep inside the body of boost. Boost uses lots of using namespace directives.

Comment: That won't work and it is futile to try

Comment: The device port is already working for some special functions. I have hope but agree it is pretty ambitious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only guess here, but my best guess is that for some reason there is a missing closing curly brace to close the `boost` namespace somewhere before the `std` namespace is opened, probably by including a standard library header. This then causes the namespace `boost::std` to exist so the compiler looks in that sub-namespace for `std::ptrdiff_t` as the `boost` namespace is currently open.

E.g. compiling the following source file with gcc

```
#include <cstddef>

namespace foo {

// this creates a namespace ::foo::std
#include <typeinfo>

}

namespace foo {
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
}
```

also prints

```
prog.cc:11:34: error: 'ptrdiff_t' in namespace 'foo::std' does not name a type
   11 |     using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

as you can also see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Seqz8YFTSouK8ZP3).

Comment: Thank you - this was it. Much appreciated!